# Is there a better way to create a collision between two objects?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection

The character I created often overlaps with the obstacles that are meant to cause a game over. The character is the flyCopter, which is a group of png's that make up the whole character. The blockTmp's are the obstacles which are made of a combination of png's as well.

Sometimes the character does not collide enough and you can get away without a game over but obviously it should not have to overlap. It should be game over when they two collide instantly. It's just weird how sometimes it will "die" on contact and then other times it really needs to overlap.

Thank you

//CHARACTER COLLISION

```
-(void)checkGameOver{
if(GAMESTART){
if(flyCopter.position.x >= CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - flyCopter.copterWidth/2 - 6){
  [self showOver];
}

if(flyCopter.position.x <= CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + flyCopter.copterWidth/2 + 6){
  [self showOver];
}

[self compareCP:blockTmp1 :flyCopter];
[self compareCP:blockTmp2 :flyCopter];
if(flyCopter.position.y <= blockTmp1.position.y - 0 + blockTmp1.size.height + 0)
if(flyCopter.position.x <= blockTmp1.position.x +20 + blockTmp1.size.width + 0)

{
    [self compareCP:blockTmp3 :flyCopter];
    [self compareCP:blockTmp4 :flyCopter];
}

[self compareCP:blockTmp5 :flyCopter];
[self compareCP:blockTmp6 :flyCopter];
if(flyCopter.position.y <= blockTmp5.position.y - 0 + blockTmp5.size.height + 0)
if(flyCopter.position.x <= blockTmp5.position.x +20 + blockTmp5.size.width + 0)

{
    [self compareCP:blockTmp7 :flyCopter];
    [self compareCP:blockTmp8 :flyCopter];
}

[self compareCP:blockTmp9 :flyCopter];
[self compareCP:blockTmp10 :flyCopter];
if(flyCopter.position.y <= blockTmp9.position.y - 0 + blockTmp9.size.height + 0)
  if(flyCopter.position.x <= blockTmp9.position.x +20 + blockTmp9.size.width + 0)

{
    [self compareCP:blockTmp11 :flyCopter];
    [self compareCP:blockTmp12 :flyCopter];
  }
}
}


-(void)compareCP:(SKSpriteNode*)flyCopters : (SKSpriteNode*)blocks{
if(flyCopters){
    if ([blocks intersectsNode:flyCopters]) {
        [self showOver];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Box2d for better collision .